# How many lightweight nodes vs full nodes are there on the network?

Tags: network, nodes, peer-discovery, thin-clients

I'm curious, how many lightweight nodes are there on the network? Is this easy to tell?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't easy to tell for a number of reasons.

- The network protocols don't explicitly distinguish between full-nodes, SPV wallets or other types of software that communicate with full nodes.
- Many lightweight wallets only connect to predetermined non-public servers, as Murch pointed out.
- Just finding approximately all the current nodes in the network is itself difficult

  - Some nodes are only intermittently present. Consider a node that is only connected for 10 minutes a week.
  - The network is a gossip network. It isn't intended that anyone needs a list of all nodes. Therefore finding all nodes isn't explicitly catered for.
  - Many nodes are likely to be relatively passive and may not accept inbound connections.
  - Privacy is an important issue. This probably affects the amount of information leaked by software - even if that information seems innocuous to many.
  - Nodes that use security measures such as Tor may be hard to count accurately - they might each appear as multiple nodes.

---

related:

- [Are all wallets always considered nodes?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/115323/13866)

Comment: Additionally a lot of light clients only connect to predetermined non-public endpoints

Comment: @Murch: Thanks, I've added that point to the answer.

Comment: Perhaps that's a semantics issue, but if a (lightweight) wallet connects to a non-public wallet service, I wouldn't refer to that as a P2P node at all. So if the question is about lightweight *nodes*, they don't matter. Of course, perhaps OP's question is really about lightweight wallets in a more general sense.